# Discrete wavelet transformation on image using 'haar' wavelet in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, haar-wavelet, dwt

I am trying to apply haar wavelet on an image in python. Here is the code

```
from pywt import dwt2, idwt2
img = cv2.imread('xyz.png')
cA, (cH, cV, cD) = dwt2(img, 'haar')
```

Then I modify coefficients embedding some data like given below

```
cH1=cH+k*pn_sequence_h
cV1=cV+k*pn_sequence_v
```

After that, I apply idwt with below code

```
idwt2(cA,(cH1,cV1,cD),'haar')[:Mc,:Nc]
```

where Mc and Nc are height and width of decomposed image.

But, I get an error with this code. Below is an error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "dwt.py", line 15, in <module>
 idwt2(cA,(cH1,cV1,cD),'haar')[:Mc,:Nc]
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywt\_multidim.py", line 104, in idwt2
 LL, (HL, LH, HH) = coeffs
 ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What should I do in order to fix this error? I am new to python. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried like this in below code. But here I don't get coefficients like CA, CH, CV, CD. what I get is all coefficients together.

```
import numpy as np
import pywt
import numpy
import PIL
from PIL import Image
img = PIL.Image.open("rot.png").convert("L")
imgarr = numpy.array(img) 
coeffs = pywt.dwt2(imgarr, 'haar')
pywt.idwt2(coeffs, 'haar')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

`idwt2((cA,(cH1,cV1,cD)),'haar')[:Mc,:Nc]`

You missed packing the coeffs in a single tuple.